# Where to implement tolerance to decide when to detect tochscreen press events and move events in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, touch, mouse

I am interested to port applications that use a mouse based interface to a touchscreen based interface and I wonder how to best avoid mis-moves when a user with "large and wiggly" fingertips uses my applications

If the user touches a certain location and his/her/its pulse or impatience causes the fingertip to wiggle around some pixels, my application should not interpret this as a `QEvent::MouseMove` and cause scrolling of e.g. a list underneath.

There seem to be two classes that do press-like events, namely `QTouchEvent` and `QMouseEvent`.

- What is the difference in respect to the above issue with reliably detecting the users intent? Does `QTouchEvent` solve that issue for me?
- Do I need to add event handlers for `QTouchEvent`, in parallel to `QMouseEvent` (in order to provide backward compatibility with mouse users)?

I imagine that it would not be a good idea to implement this sort of tolerance in every widget again, but there should be some global instance that makes this work, in e.g. QApplication or X11 directly.

Comment: Why do you think touch events would be interpreted as mouse move?

Comment: @LaszloPapp because if you have a widget that can be clicked on and can be moved, and you press it and move the mouse and release it, then you need to decide whether you move the widget or press it. Think about a list of buttons. You want to be able to scroll the list, but you want to be able to click the buttons too. If you press and release the list and don't move in between, you probably want to delegate those events to the button underneath so that it is clicked. But if you move in between, you probably want to scroll the list instead and don't click the button.

Comment: In that case, you do not move the mouse, but your finger, no? If the mouse move event is still generated, I would personally consider it as a bug.

Comment: @LaszloPapp edited my comment ^^ now you can implement this "moved or clicked" test yourself, or you can ask Qt or X11 to implement a sensible detection, which is the root of my question. "you do not move the mouse, but your finger, no? " -> your finger is your mouse in a touch based gui, no? One part of my question is the difference between touch and mouse events, which you seem to be able to answer. If so, please go ahea.

Comment: This is all very platform specific (e.g. touch input will generate synthetized mouse events on some systems, which Qt will not filter out for you). Consequently, there is no general guideline on how to handle competing mouse and touch messages. You will have to figure this out for your target platform(s), and test on all platform(s) if you need to support more than just one.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `QApplication::startDragDistance()`. This is application wide accessible. If this only needs to be checked in one part of your application (e.g. small sized elements in a list), you can still use a self defined distance. Then just reimplement `QWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)` and include (from the docs):

```
if ((startPos - currentPos).manhattanLength() >= QApplication::startDragDistance())
     startTheDrag();
```